# Winforms Chart not displaying x-axis labels in ascending/descending order

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, charts

[image]

The .net desktop-application receives response from the micro-controller and plots the data to the graph on time interval basis. If you look into the red-circled x-axis labels, you'll not find them in ordered manner. 
Eg. -20.0 should come before -20.4. 
The problem is, if you look into the code:

```
   chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(rLabData[0], rLabData[1]);
```

'AddXY' according to msdn doc: Adds a DataPoint object to the end of the collection, with the specified X-value and Y-values(s). 
**This is the problem, I don't not want the data points to be added at the end of previous result rather within the maximum and minimum value of X-axis defined in scale**
If the input points is given at the same instance it works fine, but upon regular interval basis, the chart in winform doesn't display desired result.

Comment: L*ab - colorimeter by any chance?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Share some more code! (Charttype, Label format, CustomLabels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question can be answered: If you don't want the new `DataPoints` to be **added** at the end of the `Points` collection, you need to **insert** them at the right spot.

Here is an example for inserting a `DataPoint(yourXValue, yourYValue)` into a  `Series S`:

```
    // we try to find the DataPoint right after our X-Value:
    DataPoint dp = S.Points.FirstOrDefault(p => p.XValue > yourXValue);
    if (dp != null)
    {
        // got it, so we insert before it..
        int index = S.Points.IndexOf(dp);
        if (index >= 0) S.Points.InsertXY(index, yourXValue, yourYValue);
    }
    // no, so we add to the end
    else S.Points.AddXY(yourXValue, yourYValue);
```

Unfortunately I have doubts that your `Label` problem really is caused by adding..

- Your chart looks like it is `ChartType.Point`. For this type the order of the `DataPoints` doesn't show, as opposed to other types, like `Line`..
- And the `Labels` shouldn't be out of order with any type, unless you add (wrong) `CustomLabels`..?